# SSL confluent-kafka-dotnet librdkafka SSL

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, confluent-platform

Im having an issue getting the confluent-kafka-dotnet library working with SSL. Everything works fine withouth SSL and i can get SSL working by using kafkas own scritps as below.

```
> .\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list domain.net:9094 --topic
busit-test --producer.config client-ssl.properties
```

client-ssl.properties content:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=C:/Certificates/store.jks
ssl.truststore.password=mysecret
```

i got the ca in a file cert.crt and thats how i got the store.jks by using:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore store.jks -alias issuing -file cert.crt
```

To use confluent-kafka-dotnet i need to configure it according to the documentation ( https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SSL-with-librdkafka ).

```
metadata.broker.list=at_least_one_of_the_brokers
security.protocol=ssl

# CA certificate file for verifying the broker's certificate.
ssl.ca.location=ca-cert

# Client's certificate
ssl.certificate.location=client_?????_client.pem

# Client's key
ssl.key.location=client_?????_client.key

# Key password, if any.
ssl.key.password=abcdefgh
```

i transform the cert.crt file to a .pem by using:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in cert.crt -out cert.pem -text
```

That gives me a valid pem that i can read with a texteditor. 
I then point at that pem file from the ssl.ca.location 
The brokers are configured to not validate clients but when i start my client producer i get the following error log:

```
Connected to ipv4#xx.xxx.xx.xx:9094
failed: err: Local: SSL error: (errno: No error)
Broker changed state CONNECT -> DOWN
```

I have tried everything i can think of but cant get it to work. since it works with the scripts i can download from kafka im sure there is nothing wrong with the brokers.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: On what platform fo you run? (windows, ubuntu, mac...) and which version of confluent-kafka-dotnet are you using?

Comment: Also, can you set config `debug`to `broker,security` and post the log?

Comment: i am using windows 7. Confluent.Kafka 0.11.0. connecting with kafkas own scripts work fine as i mentioned. i just make a jks from the CA crt that i have and add it to the truststore. here is a paste of the logs. i removed all real ips and broker addresses but other than that it is just copied. it seems its connecting fine and then loosing connection ever so often. even during the time it is connected i cant get any produced messages through. log here: https://pastebin.com/av3fjnH4 .

Comment: Connect meens connecting - you want UP in your logs

Comment: Will try to replicate it when I have time - I don't use SSL in my dayto day deployment, but the only time I did, I had had no issue.

Comment: librdkafka 0.11.1 fixes some SSL stability issues on Windows. Suggest you try the new release.

Comment: Updated to the latest version (0.11.3) but still get the same issue. here is a paste of the log https://pastebin.com/E0ySyCBi

Comment: @limlim did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using SSL Certificates to securely connect to Kafka using Dotnet Console App

Nuget packages to install (Package Manager Console)

```
Install-Package Confluent.Kafka
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ApplicationName": "DotNetConsoleClientForStrimziKafka",
  "KafkaClientConfig": {
    "bootstrap.servers": "<PublicIP_of_LoadBalancer>:9094",
    "security.protocol": "SSL",
    "ssl.ca.location": "C:\\kafkacerts\\ca.crt",
    "ssl.certificate.location": "C:\\kafkacerts\\user.crt",
    "ssl.key.location": "C:\\kafkacerts\\user.key"
  }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
appsettingsConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory)
  .AddJsonFile(DefaultSettingsJsonFile, false, true)
  .Build();


var configProperties = appsettingsConfig.GetSection(configSectionName).GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(configProperties);

using var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(producerConfig).Build();
```

You need to download and put decoded certificates in folder (`C:\kafkacerts` in my case).

See details: [Using SSL Certificates For Kafka Dotnet Client](https://hovermind.com/azure-kubernetes-service/acessing-kafka-running-on-aks#using-ssl-certificates-for-dotnet-client)